# microsoft access automated copy from one table to another

Tags: ms-access

I am new to access and have mostly worked with SQL Server.  I am trying to accomplish a task for our users and am not sure how to approach it.

We have a situation where the users need to manipulate some data in various access tables, then put the final results into one of several 'linked tables' that are defined in SQL Server and linked to access.  The sql server tables will defined very generically with column names like 'col1', 'col2' etc to allow for different types of data to be uploaded.

What I would like to do is have some kind of macro or module that does this:
 1) Lets the user select the source (access table)
 2) Lets the user select destination (linked sql server) table
 3) Lets the user map the columns he would like to copy from the source to the destination table. (If this is too difficult then just something that would copy the first x number of columns would work).
 4) Deletes all pre-existing data from the target table
 5) Copies all data from the source table to the target table.

Could someone give me an idea as to what would be the best approach or maybe even an example of some code that does something similar?  Thanks in advance.  We are using Microsoft Access 2010.

Comment: Yes, but it would need to delete all the rows from the target table first.

Comment: @user1686766 As the target table is on SQL server and you need to empty the table first, I suggest running a **pass-through query** using the simple **TRUNCATE TABLE TableName**